# PNG transparency causes fully transparent images when dynamically shown/hidden

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, png, iepngfix

I'm using this PNG hack for IE6 users. The problem is that `onload`, most of my PNGs are in a div which is `display: none`. But according to what the user does, I show various PNGs.

Now, the initial PNGs which are displayed `onload` are fine. They have a transparent background and look great. But the dynamically shown images later on are FULLY transparent, i.e., I can see the wrapping elements resize when the images are supposed to show up, but I cannot see the images.

The hack I'm using is

```
<!-- IE6 png files transparent background hack -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> 
<script language="JavaScript">
function correctPNG() // correctly handle PNG transparency in Win IE 5.5 & 6.
{
   var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
   var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])
   if ((version >= 5.5) && (document.body.filters)) 
   {
       for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++)
       {
            var img = document.images[i]
            var imgName = img.src.toUpperCase()
            if (imgName.substring(imgName.length-3, imgName.length) == "PNG")
            {
            var imgID = (img.id) ? "id='" + img.id + "' " : ""
            var imgClass = (img.className) ? "class='" + img.className + "' " : ""
            var imgTitle = (img.title) ? "title='" + img.title + "' " : "title='" + img.alt + "' "
            var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + img.style.cssText;
            if (img.align == "left") imgStyle = "float:left;" + imgStyle
            if (img.align == "right") imgStyle = "float:right;" + imgStyle
            if (img.parentElement.href) imgStyle = "cursor:hand;" + imgStyle
            var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
            + " style=\"" + "width:" + img.width + "px; height:" + img.height + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"
            + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
            + "(src=\'" + img.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>" 
            img.outerHTML = strNewHTML
            i = i-1
         }
      }
   }    
}
window.attachEvent("onload", correctPNG);
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Edit: Markup for the actual page

```
<a href="#">
        <em>
            <span class="tablabel">Receivers</span>
            <span class="incompletetab completed-icon" id="ini__receivers__completed"> <img src="../../images/check.png"> </span>
    </em>
</a>
```

Comment: You don't have to check for IE >= 5.5 anymore, that version really *is* dead. BTW, can you show the `div` markup (including the original `img`) and the JavaScript that shows your `div`?

Comment: So, I'm changing the class of the `span` from `incompletetab`(`display:none;`) to `completetab`(`display:inline-block;`)

Comment: Ha, wish I could mate. Unfortunately, IE6 is used by the majority of our userbase

Comment: @Jason — There's no need to shout.